# Regex to match exact substring java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as below

```
TestFilter('value') AND LoadTestFilter('value1') AND UserFilter(value2) OR TestFilter('value3')
```

I want to extract only TestFilter along with brackets from the above string.
I want regex to match only these two substrings

```
 TestFilter('value')
 TestFilter('value3')
```

I have tried below regex

```
.*TestFilter\\((.*?)\\).*
```

It is working but it is also matching LoadTestFilter in the string

How to match only TestFilter.

Comment: `TestFilter\\((.*?)\\)`

Comment: `\b` matches a word boundary in regex expressions.

Comment: @Pranav C Balan No it is matching LoadTestFilter also

Comment: @ AJNeufeld If I use this word boundary it is not matching at all

Comment: Did you properly escape the backslash in `\b`?  As in, inside a Java string, you need `\\b` to produce `\b`.

Comment: yes i have done that

Comment: Post your [mcve] code, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = "TestFilter('value') AND LoadTestFilter('value1') AND UserFilter(value2) OR TestFilter('value3')";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bTestFilter\\(.*?\\)").matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```

Explanation:

The key thing here is `\b`, which matches a *word boundary*. `\b` in the regex I used matches a word boundary at the very start of the match, and before `TestFilter`. Translating to a less regex-like language, we don't want any letters before `TestFilter`.

According to your comment, you see to have tried `.*\bTestFlter\(.*?\)`. This does not work because of the `.*` at the front. You're basically matching a bunch of random characters, followed by a word boundary, "TestFilter" then a pair of brackets with random stuff in it. This will match the whole string, since the last instance of `TestFilter` is preceded by a word boundary, then a bunch of random characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TestFilter\\((.*?)\\).*
```

without first (.*)

Answer (score 0):

`\b` matches a word boundary in regex expressions.
So `\bTestFilter` will match `"TestFilter"` but not `"LoadTestFilter"`, because there is no word boundary between `"Load"` and `"Test"`.

Thus, you could use:

```
\\bTestFilter\\((.*?)\\)
```

or

```
.*\\bTestFilter\\((.*?)\\).*
```

depending on how you are matching the input (e.g., `match()` -vs- `find()`)

---

`Matcher#find` example:

```
String haystack = "TestFilter('value') AND LoadTestFilter('value1') AND UserFilter(value2) OR TestFilter('value3')";
Matcher needle = Pattern.compile("\\bTestFilter\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(haystack);

while(needle.find()) {
    System.out.format("[%s] found in [%s]%n", needle.group(1), needle.group());
}
```

Output:

```
['value'] found in [TestFilter('value')]
['value3'] found in [TestFilter('value3')]
```

Comment: I am using matcher find so i have used .*\bTestFilter\\((.*?)\\).* but it is matching LoadTestFilter also